# GDAL VRT maximum length of LUIT

Tags: raster, gdal, vrt

In a virtual raster table's XML the LUT element can be used to specify a table lookup. To my understanding this could be used for some kind of reclass. This comes in really handy when different rasters are to be harmonized.

the Example Element in the  Section
0:0,2345.12:64,56789.5:128,2364753.02:255

However, I experience problems when the LUT section gets too long. In my case I want to put approx 1000 values in the list.
Does anybod know if there is a limit? And if so, which one?

If the limit is small, can the same raster be referenced more than once in a VRT and differen LUTs be appllied?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my own mistake. 
When a value in the LUT is repeated (like 1:23, 1:24), the error occurs, otherwise a very long LUT was accepted.

However, would be nice to know limitations.